# How to Add javascript variable inside html attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a form and I want to add javascript variable inside the value="".  value="embedurl"
I am new to adding javascript variable inside html, so far, all of the solutions that i found on google is not working. How to do this? Thanks.

```
<form id="landing2" action="https://example.com/post10/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value=" var embedurl ">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
var embedurl ="https://" + document.location.host + "/embed" + window.location.pathname;
    document.getElementById('landing2').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: `name` is a really bad value for the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

```
var embedurl ="https://" + document.location.host + "/embed" + window.location.pathname;
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value = embedurl; // here you need to set the input value
document.getElementById('landing2').submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a javascript value, you must do it by javascript.

First, you need to get the dom input element, then set the value

```
var form = document.getElementById("landing2");
var input = form["name"];

input.value = embedurl;
```

Comment: Forms have a built-in `name` property already, which your code is reading. Remember `form["name"]` does exactly the same as `form.name`. Compare https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/name and the corresponding attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-name

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this trivial code. Because the asker is a begginer, I dont want him to think that form.name is some intrinsic property of the dom form element.

Comment: Well, that results in your code suggestion not doing what it is supposed to do, and leaving the asker not understanding why.